# Initializing object with indeterminate value

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior

Does the following invoke undefined behavior?

```
int x;
int i = x;
```

Reference from C++03

> (4.1/1) If the object to which the lvalue refers is not an object of type T
>   and is not an object of a type derived from T, or **if the object is
>   uninitialized**, a program that necessitates this conversion has
>   undefined behavior.

**Edit:**
However, from (3.3.1/1) an object may be initialized with its own indetermine value, why is that? i.e.

```
int x = x; //not an undefined behaviour
```

Comment: I'd say it depends on the compiler you're using. But yes, it's mainly an undefined behavior to the point of view of a programmer. Usually, you'll get garbage on both `x` and `i`.

Comment: @frarees "_it depends on the compiler_" No. Something either has defined behaviour or not.

Comment: Well I just said that because I've heard that some compilers assume value 0 for `x` when defined and no value assigned. Also, in this case when I talk about behavior I refer to the value it finally gets.

Comment: @frarees But what some compilers **happen to do** has nothing to do with defined behavior. Compiler writers can make undocumented technical choices and change these later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because you're reading the value of a variable (`x`) which was uninitialised and unassigned.

Comment: @user1086635 I'm not sure what section of the standard you are referring to because 3.3.1 is about scopes, and I don't know what the /1 means.

Comment: @user1086635 oh, I was looking at 3.1.1 I guess. I'm not sure, I guess they're just using it to say that the name doesn't refer to the outer `x` but to the `x` that has just been declared (i.e. the name immediately hides the outer `x` even before you get to the `=`). I don't think they're saying that it's valid. Actually, I'm not sure whether it's UB or not just because they used it as an example and didn't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined if `x` is uninitialized, as said in your quote.

```
int x; // 0 initialized
int i = x;

int main() {
  int z; // not initialized
  int k = z; // UB
}
```

Comment: "_0 initialized for built-in types_" Hug?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to remember is that this is okay:

```
static int x;
int j = x;
```

but your example is not.

Answer (score -1):

It invokes perfectly defined behavior. Whatever garbage value x was when it is allocated on the stack will be assigned to i as is.

Depending on your compiler, however, you may get a compile time warning about referencing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: No, accessing the value of an uninitialised and unassigned variable is UB.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Does this mean that if the value `x` happens to be `3`, the value of `i` could be different from `3`?

Comment: @Dennis yes, or the compiler could explode, or it could order pizza, or anything else could happen. It's pointless to speculate because the standard _defines it to be undefined_.

Comment: It even means the compiler is permitted to make demons fly out of your nose. More realistically, the compiler may go on an "optimization" rampage which is assumes whatever it wants about the value of `i` and `x`, leading of course to code unlike what you expect (I remember seeing a question where GCC turned an `if (uninitializedBool) stmt;` into and unconditional `stmt;`).

Comment: I want  my compiler to order pizza and pay for it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie When you find a compiler that orders pizza if you access the value of an uninitialized variable, please forward it to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Long as it doesn't pay in bytes. I want the pizza intact. (Har har har)

Comment: @Xaade will do, but be forewarned that the compiler might pay for it with your credit card.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Not speculating, just checking if I understood correctly. +1 for pizza.

Answer (score -1):

> int x = x; //not an undefined behaviour

Wrong.

Comment: They use it as an example in the standard. I guess that doesn't mean they were saying its ok though.

Comment: Indeed. I don't like the practice of mentioning some code, and not saying very clearly that it is not allowed code... You can contact the C++ committee.